# Forward traffic from Ionos domain to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a domain from Ionos and I deployed my web application on AWS Elasticbeanstalk.
Everything is working fine on EBS, but now I want to link my domain and the EBS environment together.

My attempts:
I read that on AWS documentation that one has to create an Alias record not a Cname.
The equivalent of "Alias" records in Ionos DNS is the "A" record (like GoDaddy as well).
However, I am prompted to enter the IPv4 address of the EBS which I do not have.

Comment: Just use regular CNAME.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the regular Cname as Marcin proposed, however, I got 419 errors when my database is queried (but the frontend is there).
I bought another domain from Route 53, added an "Alias" record and the database works fine.